# How to escape special characters from JSON when assign it to Java String?

Tags: java, json, string, getstring

I'm trying to assign a value from JSON to Java String, but the JSON value is including some special characters `\`. When I was trying to assign it to the string it gave an error.

This is the JSON value:

```json
"ValueDate":"\/Date(1440959400000+0530)\/"
```

This is how I trying to use it:

```java
HistoryVO.setValueDate(DataUtil.getDateForUnixDate(historyJson.getString("ValueDate")));
```

or

[image]

Comment: So you want tog get rid of the special character?? just Date(1440959400000+0530)

Comment: What format of String does `DataUtil.getDateForUnixDate(String)` expect?

Comment: yes  Rod_Algonquin i want to get  Date(1440959400000+0530)  only.

@Elliott i want just only to get Date(1440959400000+0530) part, because in my programme there are several type Date format we are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have specific character, `(` and `)`, use `substring` method to get the value.

```
    String value = "\\/Date(1440959400000+0530)\\/";
    int start = value.indexOf("(");
    int last = value.lastIndexOf("0");
    value = value.substring(start + 1, last + 1);
    System.out.println(value); <--- 1440959400000+0530

    DataUtil.getDateForUnixDate(value);
```

I don't know `DataUtil.getDateForUnixDate()` method, but take care of `+` character because of it is not number string.

**Update**

To remove `/` character use `replace` method.

```
    String value = "/Date(1440959400000+0530)/";
    value = value.replace("/", "");
    System.out.println(value);
```

output

```
Date(1440959400000+0530)
```

Comment: No CycDemo the thing is  value = "\/Date(1440959400000+0530)\/" not value = "\\/Date(1440959400000+0530)\\/". thats the problem. there are no double \ in the json value.

Comment: My target to say is, if you have `(` and `)`, use `substring` method

Answer (score 2):

Given that

> I want ... to get [the] Date(1440959400000+0530) part,

I would use

```
String value = "/Date(1440959400000+0530)/";
int pos1 = value.indexOf("Date(");
if (pos1 > -1) {
  int pos2 = value.indexOf(")", pos1);
  if (pos2 > pos1) {
    value = value.substring(pos1, pos2 + 1);
    System.out.println(value);
  }
}
```

Output is

```
Date(1440959400000+0530)
```

Note: This works by looking for "Date(" and then the next ")", and it removes everything not between those two patterns.

Comment: the problem is it can not make string "\/Date(1440959400000+0530)\/" like this. because of "\". JSON is comming like this "ValueDate":"\/Date(1440959400000+0530)\/"

Comment: @MacDaddy Those must be Strings, and not compile time literals. It's fine with the code above because I ignore *everything* to the left of "Date(" and then everything to the right of ")".

Answer (score 1):

Mac,

As you asked for something like

```
String ValueDate = "\/Date(1440959400000+0530)\/";
```

The above one is not possible in java string, As it shows as invalid escape sequence, So replace the slash '\' as double slash '\' as below,

```
String ValueDate = "\\/Date(1440959400000+0530)\\/";
```

If am not clear of our question, pls describe it clearly

Regards,
Hari

Comment: yes Hari json string is comming like "\/Date(1440959400000+0530)\/"
but i couldnt anable to parse it as a Java String. so before assign it to the string i want to format or split it.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer for my own question.

```
historyJson.getString("ValueDate");
```

this return the String like  `/Date(1440959400000+0530)/`

now i can split it. thank you all for the help.

regards, macdaddy